# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence while creating n-dimentional array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a n-dimentional numpy array. Following is my code

```
import numpy as np
random_weights = np.empty(3)
random_weights[0] = np.array([0,1,2])
random_weights[1] = np.array([3,4,5])
```

Above code gives me `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` error. I am trying to create multi-dimentional array. What is the reason for this issue?

Comment: How about `random_weights = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5]])` ?

Comment: it is not the way i need to do it, i want to assign values on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a 2d array, you need to define it.

```
import numpy as np

random_weights = np.empty((2, 3))  # 2 rows, 3 columns
random_weights[0] = np.array([0,1,2])
random_weights[1] = np.array([3,4,5])
```

Comment: This indexing could also be written as `random_weights[0,:] = [0,1,2]`, emphasizing that it is filling in the 0'th row.